# Datepicker change date format and submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, form-submit

I have found one useful range datepicker (with only one input field):

http://bseth99.github.io/projects/jquery-ui/4-jquery-ui-datepicker-range.html

I have changed the format from 'mm/dd/yy' to 'yy-mm-dd', it works so far user selects two different dates. If the user chooses the same date for start and end, the format is still the default - 'mm/dd/yy'. How can i change this ?

The second part of my problem is to submit the form. I have tried that, but it doesnt work:

```
.datepicker({
    onChange: function () {
        $('#exchange_search').submit();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to submit the form. Still remains the problem with the single date format.

Here is the solution if someone needs it:

```
onAfterUpdate: function ( inst ) {
    $('<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all" data-handler="hide" data-event="click">Done</button>')
    .appendTo($('#jrange div .ui-datepicker-buttonpane'))
    .on('click', function () { 
        $('#jrange div').hide();
        $('#exchange_search').submit();
    });
}
```